# Cannot register COM DLL built with VS2012/VC++ on 32-bit machine

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, com, mfc, atl

I built a C++ based COM object using Visual Studio 2012. It registers and works fine on 64-bit machines (called by 32-bit code and calling a 32-bit out-of-process COM server) but does not register on 32-bit machines (neither XP nor Win7 32-bit). The message from regsvr32 is

```
LoadLibrary("comobj.dll") failed - The specified procedure could not be found.
```

The project was originally built with Visual Studio 6 (7 years ago). It uses ATL macros such as BEGIN_COM_MAP and BEGIN_SINK_MAP to declare its implementation of various interfaces. It had to be re-compiled because the COM server it was invoking changed (new ProgID, new GUID, new type library, etc). Other than making those adjustments, and using current VS, there were no (intentional) changes -- there certainly was nothing in the old equivalent of the project file that would have pointed to 64-bitness.

Examining the DLL with the 64-bit version of DEPENDS.EXE shows "64" icons next to the standard referenced DLLs like KERNEL32 and USER32. Other than having built the DLL on a 64-bit machine, there is nothing "64-bit" about the DLL that I can find. The target is explicitly Win32 (not X64).

Examining the DLL with the 32-bit version of DEPENDS.EXE (on Windows XP running under Virtual PC) shows KERNEL32.DLL with a red icon, apparently because there are references to FlsAlloc FlsFree FlsGetValue FlsSetValue that do not exist in the 32-bit KERNEL32.DLL. (I have no idea what those are and don't know where those references come from -- perhaps from the copy of MFC on the 64-bit machine where the compile was done?)

Could it be that I have to install VS2012 on XP and re-compile there? How could that really be what needs to be done to build a Win32 COM object in C++ using current Visual Studio?

Does anyone know where I might look? I've checked all the project and solution options and nothing seems set to 64-bit. The option under "Use of MFC" is set to "Use Standard Windows Libraries" -- that's probably the answer but if that's not portable to 32-bit Windows it's hardly using only "standard libraries". (I will be trying changes to that after sending this.)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Building with Visual Studio 2012, you need to use [`v110_xp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj851139.aspx) toolset to stay XP compatible.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I'll update this when I learn if that was all I needed to do to fix this.

Comment: Using that information I was able to get things working. Please add an answer with the same info (delete the comment if you like) and I will mark it as such -- that's the least I can do as you saved me a lot of time by pointing me in exactly the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default toolset coming with Visual Studio 2012 produces output incompatible with Windows XP, through using certain APIs introduced only later with Vista.

In order to both utilize the power and feature richness of the latest Microsoft C++ compiler, and be still compatible with Windows XP, you need to use an alternate toolset codename "v110_xp" introduced with Visual Studio 2012 Update 1. At the moment the latest update available is [Visual Studio Update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305), and you might want to simply install latest available updates for Visual Studio.

You have the setting available under Project Settings:

[image]

See more here: [Configuring C++ 11 Programs for Windows XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj851139.aspx).

Comment: You are right, but his core problem is that he doesn't have *any* updates installed yet.  He is still using the RTM version of the CRT, the one that has a direct dynamic link dependency on FlsAlloc().  You can recommend [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)

Comment: @HansPassant: Sure, I mentioned update 1 but it makes sense to install latest update, which is update 3. I added the link above, thanks.

Comment: I easily found "update 3" when searching for updates to VS2012 -- this answer was valuable in that it pointed me in exactly the right direction. I was lucky not to have asked this during the time after "update 2" had appeared, breaking the XP support provided by "update 1". The work I had to do to get things working was trivial. The biggest mystery is how VS2012 RTM could default to "no support for XP (for C++)" without -- for example -- warning you of the issue when you installed support for C++.